# Prevent RecyclerView item from detaching

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textureview

I have a RecyclerView, one of its item views contains a TextureView. If I scroll this item outside the screen boundaries, the item view will be detached from RecyclerView, which leads to context loss in TextureView. TextureView will be redrawn again, if the item view will appear on the screen again.

My goal is to prevent this redrawing. For now, I see only one solution for this problem - prevent RecyclerView detach its item view. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try to Put this line in starting of onbindViewHolder.

holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Comment: This should prevent views from recreating. You try another solution?

Comment: This doesn't prevents them from detaching tho